# How to prevent a JS object, initialised in the home page and updated in other pages, to be initialized again when the user goes back to home

Tags: javascript, jquery

I guess I'm posing a silly question, if so thank you for your patience.

In my `home.html` I have

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    [...]
    var taskObj = {};
    localStorage.setItem('task_object', JSON.stringify(taskObj));
    [...]
  }
</script>
```

In `another_page.html`

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    [...]
    var taskObj_a = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('task_object') || '{}');
    taskObj_a.name = "a new task";
    localStorage.setItem('task_object', JSON.stringify(taskObj_a));     
    [...]
  }
</script>
```

When the user is redirected to home.html, the taskObj gets initialised again and I lose the "name" property set in `another_page.html`.

How can I avoid this and do not reset the `taskObj`?

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the item already exists in local storage and only set it if it doesnt.

```
if(!localStorage.getItem('task_object')) localStorage.setItem('{}')
```

Comment: thank you, with your help I could find the solution,     if(localStorage.getItem('taskObj') == undefined){
// init var taskObj } else {// get taskObj}